Kemp Load Balancer with SSL Acceleration - SSL on servers, too?
We have three webservers on a local network that I have fronted with a Kemp Load Balancer.  Currently, all three have an SSL certificate on them.  Everything works as it should.  However, I wanted to explore using the SSL Acceleration option, and have put the certificate on the Load Balancer as well - and again, this works.  Do people typically then remove SSL from their webservers, and have the LB connect to the webservers over HTTP?  If I don't remove SSL on the webservers, it will effectively have to decrypt twice, yes?
I don't want plaintext traffic going from the webservers to the LB, so I am thinking SSL offloading isn't the right move for us - hoping someone can provide some clarification as I am not an expert in this.  The requirement is technically only that the client connection is encrypted, but truthfully, we don't want the traffic to be able to be seen in plaintext for a requirement...which, it will be able to - correct?

If you need encryption between the load balancer and the web servers very much depends on how secure the underlying network is. There is no general rule, because this might range from a small network fully controlled by you without any other users up to a local network managed by others with many complex systems in it (which might be compromised).

It sounds like you don't need SSL Termination on the Kemp Load balancers. If you have 3 servers in the cluster and they terminate their own SSL Connections that is by far the fastest and most secure method.
The two common reasons for terminating on the load balancer are:

Layer 7 manipulation is required on the load balancer to fix legacy application issues, i.e. URL redirection or cookie insertion.
Ease of maintenance for SSL certiificates in one place (although personally I find it far less scary to upgrade servers one at a time in the cluster, using the load balancer to have a safe maintenance window. Breaking the certificates on a load balancer with lots of applications is a scary situation).

Some people do it for the so called acceleration, but thats mostly marketing balloney.
The whole point of a load balanced cluster is to remove your single point of failure and increase performance, putting the SSL Termination on the backend servers is definately my preferred option where possible.
